# ArcMap Dissolve tool only dissolving a few entries

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dissolve

So I have a shapefile which is divided into 7 habitat categories, with 1845 polygons, and I am trying to dissolve it so I only have 1 line showing each habitat with the total area.

After dissolving, I can see 1804 entries in the attribute table, so it's obviously doing *something*, but it hasn't dissolved to only one of each habitat.

Comment: I think dissolving tool dissolves adjacent and overlapping polygon (AND optionally) with same attributes

Comment: Please **edit the question** to specify the parameters used (they can be found in the geoprocessing Results log).  Of specific importance: What value was in the MULTI_PART / SINGLE_PART flag?

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the parameters and results of the Dissolve Tool.

Comment: check you don't have a selection when your running the tool

Answer (score 2):

[image]

- In the Dissolve tool:  make sure you have ticked the habitat field for the dissolve field
- In the Dissolve tool:  make sure you tick or untick 'Create Multipart features' depending on the result you want.  It sounds like you should try Multipart first.
- In ArcMap: make sure you do not have any features selected

More info on the Dissolve tool:  http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm